# How include < or > character in value of property of bean in spring?

Tags: java, spring, escaping, character

I have bean like:

```xml
<bean id="test">

...........
<property name="myQuery" value="select a,b,c from table1 where rownum < 10;" />
```

Character `<` in `rownum < 10` isn't being accepted. How can I work around this?

Comment: @Mat was just fixing that for him :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [XML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML): `&lt;` for `<`, and `&gt;` for `>`